# Ext Js 2.1 Combobox Anymatch filter not working

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store, extjs2

This is my store.

```
var studentStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore ({
    fields :['value','name'],
    data :studentArray
})
```

This is my ext js combobox.

```
ddlStudentCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({                                               

    id:'ddlDocCat',
    emptyText:'Type..',
    hideTrigger:true,
    width:140,
    store: studentStore,
    applyTo:'ddlStudent',
    displayField :'name',
    forceSelection:true,
    selectOnFocus: true,
    listWidth:320,
    mode: 'local',
    listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
    typeAhead:true
});
```

I tried adding listeners, doQuery ,method overriding. But these are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this config to combobox.

```
enableKeyEvents: true,
listeners: {                                                     
    'beforequery': function(queryEvent) {
        this.store.filter('name', this.getRawValue(), true, false);
        queryEvent.combo.onLoad();
        // prevent doQuery from firing and clearing out my filter.
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set autoLoad : true for the store.
`var studentStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore ({
    fields :['value','name'],
    data :studentArray,
    autoLoad : true
})`

Comment: How is autoload connected to store filter?